# How do I define pandas.groupby aggregation functions when some columns are aggregated by "describe" and others by various other aggregators?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to summarize data from various sensors from a batch production process in order to match it to the final product using the pandas.groupby().agg({}) function.

For convenience and because we're not yet sure how some attributes are summarized best, I want to use the "describe" function for some attributes. Other attributes require several aggregation functions, e.g. ['min', 'max'].

The problem is that pandas seems to be unable to perform both operations in the same grouping operation when provided in the same dictionary.

Minimal example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Sensor_1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 3, 3, 2], 
'Sensor_2': [2, 2, 3, 3, 7, 6, 9, 2, 2, 1, 1], 
'Batch': [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]})
```

I can now use the groupby operator to perform the following grouping:

```py
df.groupby('Batch').agg({'Sensor_1': 'mean',
                        'Sensor_2': 'describe'})
```

I can also group for instance like:

```py
df.groupby('Batch').agg({'Sensor_1': ['mean', 'min'],
                        'Sensor_2': 'max'})
```

However, a definition like:

```py
df.groupby('Batch').agg({'Sensor_1': ['mean', 'min'],
                        'Sensor_2': 'describe'})
```

raises the following error:

> TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "class 'dict'"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid

Does anyone have an idea why this happens and how to solve the problem?

I am using Jupyter Hub with Python 3.6.8 and Pandas Version 0.23.0

Answer (score 0):

What you can do it basically giving all the functions of the `describe` method by defining a quantile function

```py
def quant(n):
    def quantile_(x):
        return np.quantile(x, n)
    quantile_.__name__ = 'quantile_%s' % n
    return quantile_
```

And then just:

```py
df.groupby("Batch").agg({"Sensor_1": ['mean', 'min'], 
                         "Sensor_2": ['std', 'min', quant(.25), quant(.50), quant(.75), 'max']})
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hi Jules,Thanks for the suggestion. I would however really like to understand just why it does not work...

Comment: `<rant>`It does not work simply because `agg` and buggy and does not follow its documentation`</rant>`. More seriously, `agg` has 3 types of *functions*: internal that represent methods to apply to nd.arrays or Series, external (for exemple user supplied Python functions) that are passed a Series as parameter, and describe which represents a bunch of internal functions. In parallel, `agg` accept various kind of arguments: a single function, a list of function or a dictionnary mapping them to axis labels. No surprise that corner cases are poorly handled